ComboBox only shows one rows while filtering data
I have created a dropdown in Ms-word using data from Excel und I hav added a filter-function. Both are working properly. However, when I enter something to filter I just see a single row and a little scroll bar even if there are many data:
Let assume I have 125ASD3461, 4571ANR778 and AN66723tz. If I enter "7", I will see "4571ANR778" with a little scroll bar and if I click there I will see the next one "AN66723tz". But I want to see for example at least 6 data if the filtered data are more than 6 with the scroll bar to see the others
Here my script for the filter:
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
    ' Filter the items based on the current ComboBox text
    PopulateComboBox ComboBox1.Text
End Sub

Private Sub PopulateComboBox(filterText As String)
    Dim item As Variant
    Dim currentText As String
    currentText = ComboBox1.Text ' Store the current text

    ' Clear the ComboBox before adding filtered items
    ComboBox1.Clear

    ' Loop through the collection and add items that contain the filter text
    For Each item In allItems
        ' Use InStr to find if the filterText is found anywhere in the item
        If InStr(1, UCase(item), UCase(filterText)) > 0 Then
            ComboBox1.AddItem item
        End If
    Next item

    ' Restore the typed text after filtering
    ComboBox1.Text = currentText

    ' Make sure the ComboBox shows the correct number of items (up to 6)
    If ComboBox1.ListCount > 6 Then
        ComboBox1.ListRows = 6
    Else
        ComboBox1.ListRows = ComboBox1.ListCount
    End If
End Sub

filter-function works poperly but like I said there is only one row to see instead of 6
Any suggestions?

Then, try using a ListBox. The combo box shows only one row, this is its standard behavior. Besides that, how do you intend returning back to the control not filtered items? Having two controls, a combo box keeping all the time the initial items and a filtered list box you can do what (I think) you need...

What is allItems? Is it a global variable?

@Blackcat yes I declare it at the beginning with Dim allItems As Collection.

@FaneDuru Yes, I have two controls: allItems, which contains all the items for the dropdown, and ControlBox1, which is used for the filtered items. Unfortunately, I will try ListBox

@FaneDuru It Works with ListBox and textField. Thanks for the suggestion

I tried your code and works as you required on Excel 2007.

It works if you use ListBox and a TextField as suggested by @FaneDuru
Private Sub txtSearch_Change()
    Dim searchText As String
    searchText = txtSearch.Text

    If Len(searchText) > 0 Then
        Call PopulateListBox(searchText)
    Else
        Call PopulateListBox("")
    End If
    
    txtSearch.SetFocus
End Sub


Private Sub ListBox1_Click()
    If ListBox1.ListIndex <> -1 Then
        Dim selectedItem As String
        selectedItem = ListBox1.Value
        
        If Len(selectedItem) > 0 Then
            Selection.TypeText Text:=selectedItem
            Unload Me
        End If
    End If
End Sub


Private Sub PopulateListBox(searchText As String)
    Dim i As Long
    Dim matchCount As Long

    ListBox1.Clear
    matchCount = 0
    
    For i = 1 To fullList.Count
        If InStr(1, fullList(i), searchText, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
            ListBox1.AddItem fullList(i)
            matchCount = matchCount + 1
        End If
    Next i
    
    If matchCount = 0 And Len(searchText) > 0 Then
        MsgBox "No Match", vbExclamation
        txtSearch.Text = "" 
    End If
End Sub


As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
